# how to use string indexed interface of typescript?

Tags: arrays, interface, typescript

I'd like to use string index of interface.

```
interface IDictionary {
     [index: string]: string;
}
var params: IDictionary;
params = [{ "heart": "HP" }, { "mana": "MP" }];
console.log(params);
```

I thought this might be like MAP such as a pair of key and value. I'm not sure this is correct approach.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Using the indexer limits what can be put or fetched for the object using the index syntax. E.g. `foo` is inferred to be of type `string`:

```
interface IDictionary {
     [index: string]: string;
}
var params = {} as IDictionary;

params['heart'] = 'HP'; // okay
var foo = params['heart']; // foo:string
```

The following on the other hand is an error as it will not type check:

```
var bar:number = params['heart']; // ERROR
params['heart'] = 234; // ERROR
```

Complete demo:

```
interface IDictionary {
     [index: string]: string;
}
var params = {} as IDictionary;

params['heart'] = 'HP'; // okay
var foo = params['heart']; // foo:string


var bar:number = params['heart']; // ERROR
params['heart'] = 234; // ERROR
```

Comment: Don't forget you need to initialize params.. `params = {};`

Comment: instead of hard defining the value as a string, using "any" will remove the limitation.